# How to Parsing JSON With Python in relationship

Tags: python, json, loops

I have json data with relationship but I can't loop it

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "My TEST",
        "image": "1.jpg",
        "article": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "TEST"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I try to loop like

```
myitems = []
for item in json_data['data']:
    myitems.append({
        'title': item['name'],
        'image': item['image'],
        'article_id': item['article'][0]['id']
    })
```

it tell me like

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `json_data['data']` is a dictionary. You don't need to iterate through it.

Comment: please print `json_data`. I guess you will see the problem when you do that.

Comment: I got it sry i'm new on python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "My TEST",
        "image": "1.jpg",
        "article": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "TEST"
            }
        ]
    }
}


myitems=[{
    'title': d["data"]['name'],
    'image': d["data"]['image'],
    'article_id': d["data"]['article'][0]['id']
}]
print myitems
[{'image': '1.jpg', 'article_id': 1, 'title': 'My TEST'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

As blender commented, you are running over the dictionary keys. This will work:

change

```
for item in json_data['data']
```

to

```
for item in json_data
```

But again, as blender mentioned, you don't need to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. the loop is on an article.

```
myitems = []
for item in json_data['data']['article']:
    myitems.append({
        'title': json_data['data']['name'],
        'image': json_data['data']['image'],
        'article_id': item['id']
    })
```